# Longitudinal data with different entry dates and different measurement times

Tags: panel-data, biostatistics

I have a longitudinal dataset with 22,000 patients, where patient entry dates are different. Regarding time related data, all I have are birth and measurement dates for each patient.
For example, while a patient is measured in

`"2016-04-27" "2016-05-23" "2016-06-27" "2016-07-20" "2016-07-21" "2016-07-22" "2016-07-23" "2016-07-24" "2016-07-25" "2016-07-27" "2016-07-29" "2016-07-31" "2016-08-03" "2016-08-05"`

another patient is measured in

`"2016-01-02" "2019-10-26" "2020-03-15" "2020-05-15" "2020-06-02" "2020-06-09" "2020-06-22" "2020-09-08" "2021-01-30"`

I want to study the progression of a biomarker throughout time. How would you set the variable **time** to study the progression of the response variable of interest? I mean in terms of time scale. Would you use time as number of days/weeks/months/years since the patient enters the study, age since the patient enters the study ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what question you want to answer with your study.

If you just want to know how biomarker values change with patient age, then you should set the reference `time = 0` to each patient's birth date. You might then include year of birth as another covariate in your model, to control for systematic changes over calendar time.

If patients enter the study due to some specific clinical event, like diagnosis of cancer or other disease, then it would make more sense to use that study-entry or diagnosis date as the reference `time = 0`. You might then include the age at study entry as another covariate, to control for systematic changes related to age.

The choice is thus up to you and your colleagues--whichever makes the most sense for your study.